# Excel formula to grab each header name if user name appears below in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, power-automate

I am trying to use INDEX and Match functions to return every header in a table I have when a certain username matches. So far I have not had much luck. Eventually I am trying to create an email template that will email the users manager of all applications that need to be removed so I'd like to be able to place a variable inside the excel MATCH function to search for the username which is entered in by a Microsoft form. Currently I am just trying to get a query for the headers though. Below is an image of how the sheet is laid out. I want to keep it this way since this took awhile to enter who has what application.

[image: Sheet format for Apps]

The headers are the applications and each column has the users who access the applications. I'd like to just query the headers if a username shows under a cell in that header. So far I've had trouble getting a nested INDEX and Match to work which errors out. This is the formula I tried.

```
=INDEX(Table2[[#Headers],[Designer Google Sheets]:[Amazon IT]],MATCH("TonyL",CJ4:CX6,0))
```

It returns N/A Value not available error. Any help would be appreciated on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Match does not work on 2 dimensional ranges.  It will only work on 1 column OR 1 row.

Comment: Based on Scott's comment, use an if() or perhaps max() to choose between a match for each row. an idea as no data to test. I always find that splitting out each section to find the errors works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution for you:

try using this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IFERROR(IF(SEARCH($H$3,Data)>0,Data[#Headers],""),""))
```

- "Data" is the name of your table.
- "$H$3" is the value you looking for in the table.

This is a screenshot of what I did: when you writing the customer it returns all the columns it appears in.

Hope that helps.

[my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxOCc.png)

Comment: Hi Oran, thanks so much that seems to work! Now I have to figure out how to replace the $H$3 value with an input pulled from Microsoft Forms. Thanks so much for this as that is what I needed!